# How to make a setTimeout function continuously loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

How can I make a setTimeout function continuously loop?

For example

```
setTimeout(function(){  
        $(".slide2").hide();
        $(".slide").show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".slide").hide();
            $(".slide2").show();
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout or setInterval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`setInterval` is actually evil, if the code inside the setInterval takes longer than the time you have set it will create another process before the function finishes messing everything up. So choosing `setTimeout` is actually better.

To make a function loops in `setTimeout` use a following syntax:

```
function function1() {
    console.log({} + [] + " = {} + []"); // run this it is actually funny
}

function runner() {
    function1();
    setTimeout(function() {
        runner();
    }, time);
}

runner();
```

Comment: Agreed. I personally faced many problems with `setInterval` in an application with many such loops. `setTimeout` seems to be more reliable.

Comment: I am very new to jquery! I don't understand how to use this syntax, could you perhaps give me an example? Thanks!! @Konair0s

Comment: It is not jQuery, it is pure JavaScript. `runner()` is a recursive function - it calls itself again after some amount of `time`. I.e. - when first time executed, function `runner()` will set a delay to execute anonymous function (this is what `setTimeout` for), and when time has come, it executes function `runner()` AGAIN, it executes the same function AGAIN. So it becomes basically implementation of `setInterval` function.

Comment: I would prefer to call it a not-evil implementation of `setInterval` @Konair0s

Comment: Great! Got it working perfectly! Dead easy! Thanks a lot. @Konair0s

Comment: Isn't this a infinite recursive function? Is this a problem in javascript? I'm very new to JS.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) and [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead.

```
setInterval(function () {
    $(".slide2").toggle();
    $(".slide").toggle();
}, 1000);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc6ec/)**

Comment: this seems like the simplest method? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce your nesting, and probably use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) and toggle will take care of the rest (show your first element by default before executing.).

```
function slideEm()
{
    $(".slide2").toggle(); 
    $(".slide").toggle(); // Make this visible first
    window.setTimeout(slideEm, 1000);
}

slideEm();
```

Or use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

```
function slideEm()
{
    $(".slide2").toggle(); 
    $(".slide").toggle(); // Make this visible first

}

$(function(){
     $('.slide').show(); //Using css hide both of them and show this first
    window.setInterval(slideEm, 1000); // start the callback loop with a sec interval
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KXqc4/)

Comment: @JanDvorak Have a look at the demo