# How can I return progress_hook for yt_dlp using FastApi to end user?

Tags: python, fastapi, yt-dlp

Relevant portion of my code looks something like this:

```
@directory_router.get("/youtube-dl/{relative_path:path}", tags=["directory"])
def youtube_dl(relative_path, url, name=""):
    """
    Download
    """

    relative_path, _ = set_path(relative_path)

    logger.info(f"{DATA_PATH}{relative_path}")

    if name:
        name = f"{DATA_PATH}{relative_path}/{name}.%(ext)s"
    else:
        name = f"{DATA_PATH}{relative_path}/%(title)s.%(ext)s"

    ydl_opts = {
        "outtmpl": name,
        # "quiet": True
        "logger": logger,
        "progress_hooks": [yt_dlp_hook],
        # "force-overwrites": True
    }

    with yt.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        try:
            ydl.download([url])
        except Exception as exp:
            logger.info(exp)
            return str(exp)
```

I am using this webhook/end point to allow an angular app to accept url/name input and download file to folder. I am able to logger.info .. etc. output the values of the yt_dlp_hook, something like this:

```
def yt_dlp_hook(download):
    """
    download Hook

    Args:
        download (_type_): _description_
    """

    global TMP_KEYS

    if download.keys() != TMP_KEYS:
        logger.info(f'Status: {download["status"]}')
        logger.info(f'Dict Keys: {download.keys()}')
        TMP_KEYS = download.keys()
        logger.info(download)
```

Is there a way to stream a string of relevant variables like ETA, download speed etc. etc. to the front end? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Queue object to communicate between the threads. So when you call youtube_dl pass in a Queue that you can add messages inside yt_dlp_hook (you'll need to use partial functions to construct it). You'll be best off using asyncio to run the download at the same time as updating the user something like:

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial
import threading
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
from queue import LifoQueue, Empty


def main():
    # Set the url to download
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"

    # Get the current event loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # Create a Last In First Out Queue to communicate between the threads
    queue = LifoQueue()

    # Create the future which will be marked as done once the file is downloaded
    coros = [youtube_dl(url, queue)]
    future = asyncio.gather(*coros)

    # Start a new thread to run the loop_in_thread function (with the positional arguments passed to it)
    t = threading.Thread(target=loop_in_thread, args=[loop, future])
    t.start()

    # While the future isn't finished yet continue
    while not future.done():
        try:
            # Get the latest status update from the que and print it
            data = queue.get_nowait()
            print(data)
        except Empty as e:
            print("no status updates available")
        finally:
            # Sleep between checking for updates
            asyncio.run(asyncio.sleep(0.1))


def loop_in_thread(loop, future):
    loop.run_until_complete(future)


async def youtube_dl(url, queue, name="temp.mp4"):
    """
    Download
    """

    yt_dlp_hook_partial = partial(yt_dlp_hook, queue)

    ydl_opts = {
        "outtmpl": name,
        "progress_hooks": [yt_dlp_hook_partial],
    }
    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        return ydl.download([url])


def yt_dlp_hook(queue: LifoQueue, download):
    """
    download Hook

    Args:
        download (_type_): _description_
    """
    # Instead of logging the data just add the latest data to the queue
    queue.put(download)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Also, what do I do with the queue?

Comment: You can get the most recent item with queue.get and then process that data to display it on the front-end. It really depends what your setup looks from after this point. Essentially you'll want to pass in the queue and run it in the background while polling queue to get the status updates and update some value on the front end. If you want it livestreamed back to the user then you can look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913032/modern-way-to-stream-data-to-a-web-based-angular-front-end

Comment: This may be a more applicable example shows how to stream content between flask and angular, so you open a socket and send a download start message of some sort and then stream back the status updates https://www.educba.com/flask-websocket/